# Let users download manipulated SVGs

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, svg, crop

I am currently working on a webpage on which users will be able to manipulate a SVG-file of the world map to their liking. E.g. users are able to select all European countries, highlight certain ones, and download the resulting file.

I understand that you can include download links like this:

```
<a href="/path/to/file.svg" download>
```

Now that I have not stored the modified SVG anywhere, how would I be able to let users download their modified version of the SVG?

I store the SVG inline so that I can directly manipulate its attributes from the javascript file.

I looked into cropper.js but this only works with canvas and img objects.

Comment: You should be able to output your SVG as a blob and link to it for download.

Comment: I've been using this recently, but not specifically for SVG: https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this question with jquery I'm guessing you are using that as well. Then there is a quite simple way of downloading inline svg (modified or not) as a .svg file.

Here is some inline SVG (again, modified or not) that you can download by clicking the link.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#download').attr('href', 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + btoa($("#circle").html())); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="download" download="file-name-here.svg">Download</a>

<div id="circle"><svg width="100" height="100" id="visualization" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg></div>
```